# Linking to Quartz framework or ARC error?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dynamic-linking

I have the following code to generate a "noise texture" for an NSView background.

I have already linked the target to `Cocoa` and `QuartzCore` frameworks in the build phases, but the compiler keeps complaining with the following errors:

> ARC semantic issue
>
> "Receiver 'CIFilter' for class message is a forward declaration"
>
> "Not known class method for selector filterWithName"

```
CIFilter *randomGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];
       
[randomGenerator setValue:[[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRandomGenerator"]           valueForKey:@"outputImage"]
                   forKey:@"inputImage"];
        
[randomGenerator setDefaults];
noisePattern = [randomGenerator valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

What's wrong here?.
I have already try all tricks that I can imagine off, to get rid of the errors. I know for sure this code works because it is a copy off an example project that compiles without any problems.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

However you linked your project with QuartzCore framework you still need toimport appropriate header in your implementation file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```